# Opening other applications using python

Tags: python

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on a 64bit laptop. I am trying to open an application using python code.

```
import os
os.system("open /home/utsav/ab.txt")
```

It gives the following error:

"Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console 256"

What command do I want to use?

Comment: "open a file" has no well-defined meaning under Linux. Maybe you want something like xdg-open?

Answer (score 1):

The command you're using - `open` is actually another command referred to in the man pages as `openvt`, which opens a virtual terminal.

I don't think that's what you want to do, so you would want to use another command (such as gnome-open, xdg-open, geany, gedit, vim, or nano).

Answer (score 1):

I tried this one. it works for me.

```
import os
os.system("command of your preferred app")
```

the command for app can be found from *Desktop Entry* tab of *Properties* of the preferred app.

Answer (score 0):

`open` works on OS-X, under ubuntu I end up using `gnome-open` (I don't know what the corresponding command is if you're using the k-desktop).

**EDIT**

based on the comment by Niklas B., you could probably also try `xdg-open`.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, the Python 2.7.3 documentation says that the `os` module is deprecated and the `subprocess` module should be used instead. To execute a command this way you can use `subprocess.call(args, ...)` (["Using the subprocess module"](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#using-the-subprocess-module)).

Based on the earlier answers you can use `open` for Mac OS X and `gnome-open` for a Linux distro running the Gnome desktop environment. (I checked `gnome-open` and `xdg-open` and both work on Fedora 16.) Windows is a bit tricky.

For Windows you need to use `start`, but if there are spaces in the path to the file or the filename, then it doesn't work right. Quoting the filename doesn't quite fix it, either, since `start` expects an unmarked argument with quotes around it to be a title (e.g. for a new `cmd` interface window). This is a problem since neither the title nor the file to open is a marked argument, so to get the call to work right you have to do something like `start "DummyTitle" "Filename with spaces.ext"`.

So what we've got is:

- Mac OS X: `subprocess.call(['open','/path/to/file'])`
- Linux running Gnome DE: `subprocess.call(['gnome-open','/path/to/file'])`
- Windows: `subprocess.call(['start','"DummyTitle"','"C:\\Path\\to\\File.ext"'])`

Or something like that.

---

For versions of Python before 2.7.3, you could us the `os` module with these args as strings as you suggest in your question (just altering the command portion of the system call). Note as well that there's `os.startfile('/path/to/file')` for Windows which will open the file with whatever the associated default is for that filetype, if you are going the deprecated `os` route.

---

Note that we still don't have a confirmed way of opening files on OSes using other desktop environments. Please suggest improvements to this answer!